# mutt - difference between account-hook and folder-hook

Tags: hook, account, mutt

What is the difference between account hooks and folder hooks in Mutt? If I understand Mutt correctly, it can only have one IMAP connection open at a time. So why can't I just let an account hook to set up everything?

What needs to be set in account hooks and what should be left for folder hooks and why?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the section *Managing Multiple Accounts* of the mutt HTML [manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#account-hook), the difference between `folder-hook` and `account-hook` lies in the fact that `folder-hook` is triggered when a folder is *opened* whereas `account-hook` is triggered whenever mutt tries to *connect* to the remote server of a mailbox, this happens both when you open a folder but also when you browse the list of your mailboxes (i.e. folders).